# Time in SQL is always "AM". Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My hosting service has a server in different timezone then I live (Pacific Time). I want to adjust inserting time (into ms sql database ) to my local time. (Europe). Actually here is my following code which shows correct time (let's say: 04:00:15), but in ms sql a record is always inserted as AM time (04:00:15 AM - for above case ).

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);

String dateString = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt,TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time")).ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss");
```

Doesn't matter when insertion is made (10AM, or 10PM ), records are always noted as "AM" time. Why?

I'm inserting this date as "datetime" in ms sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the lowercase "hh" timepart in your ToString call refers to 12-hour time.

You need to use capitals "HH" for 24-hour clock.

See - [Custom Date and Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (MSDN).

Comment: And this is why you should pass a date object to SQLServer rather than converting it to a string before sending it.

Comment: WoW, it works. Actually I knew this a long time ago, but I made some changes to my code, and forgot about this (didn't comment my code), and I was beating my head for this problem. Thanks again, case closed :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use strings to represent date. Use [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) in the database. Use [`SqlDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for parameters. And you'll never have to deal with questions like above.

If you *do* end up sending strings to the database, **always** specify the connection [`SET DATEFORMAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) explicitly in your app. When in doubt, use the [unseparated string format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):`yyyymmdd` because it is not affected by the current SET DATEFORMAT settings.